# Please assist with writing a Macro to clean up data entries

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

Quick question that should be easy enough for a lot of you but I'm not well versed in VBA or code in general for that matter but I have a problem that only a Macro or piece of VBA code can resolve for me. I have to edit a large number of data entries in a spreadsheet, cell by cell.

So on to the question. Could you please show me an example or provide a complete macro for me to use to edit these cells?

The editing that I require is as follows:

I need to read each cell in the following range: B2 to Q383. A typical entry that needs to be examined and edited looks like this: 629.64\3.00\01:30

What needs to happen now is for everything to the left of the first "\" and everything to the right of the second "\" needs to be removed, including the "\", from each cell.

I've tried fiddling around with the LEFT and RIGHT commands and I can output the data that needs to be removed from the cells with something like this

=left(B11, Find("\", B11) - 1)

So what would be the delete command in a macro to target that data selection in that cell? Or how do I use a delete command with those parameters?

Thanks in advance for any advice or answers!

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're after - you say you want to remove the bits from the left and right, but the formula returns the bit on the left.

Anyway, here's 3 formula to do it:
**Left:**  =TRIM(LEFT(B11,FIND("\",B11)-1))
**Middle:** =LEFT(MID(B11,FIND("\",B11)+1,LEN(B11)),FIND("\",MID(B11,FIND("\",B11)+1,LEN(B11)))-1)
**Right:** =MID(B11,FIND("\",SUBSTITUTE(B11,"\","~",1))+1,LEN(B11))

And three VBA functions to do it
(use these as you would formula - **=leftbit(B11)**, or if you're looking for something other than backslashes - **=leftbit(B11,"|")** will find the I-bar as a divider. )

```
Public Function LeftBit(target As Range, Optional Divider As String = "\") As String

    LeftBit = Trim(Left(target, InStr(target, Divider) - 1))

End Function

Public Function MiddleBit(target As Range, Optional Divider As String = "\") As String

    Dim First As Long, Second As Long

    First = InStr(target, Divider)
    Second = InStr(First + 1, target, Divider)

    MiddleBit = Mid(target, First + 1, Second - First - 1)

End Function

Public Function RightBit(target As Range, Optional Divider As String = "\") As String

    RightBit = Right(target, Len(target) - InStrRev(target, Divider))

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give these a test tomorrow morning and get back to you. The formula example I posted was just an example of part of what I was looking for but I'm confident that I can combine what you've posted here into what I'm looking for. If it doesn't already do what I am looking for! Thanks again.

Comment: I'd use the formula on a second sheet to pull everything from your original data - you can then copy/paste special values if you want to overwrite the originals.

Comment: Thanks Darren. Ended up using your middle function to move the data I wanted into another sheet then just copying the data back into the main sheet. Worked like a charm.